# What kind of planes are on this old photo?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Not sure what kind of planes are on this old photo? Does anyone have any idea?

[image: Picture of several old twin-engine planes in flight]

Answer (score 16):

This is a formation of Curtiss-Wright AT-9s officially known as the Fledgling, but also known as the Jeep.

A high resolution version of the photo is available here: [A formation of AT-9s over the Gulf of Mexico. USAF Photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/wonderyearsaviation/32071802952)

The National Museum of the US Air Force has restored an example painted to represent the aircraft in the foreground; more information can be found here: [AT-9](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/196293/curtiss-at-9-jeepfledgling/)

[image: AT-9]

Answer (score 11):

That's the Curtis-Wright AT9 Jeep.

It was a trainer aircraft produced between 1941 and 1943.

See more information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss-Wright_AT-9